# which is correct "a ear" or "an ear", conversely "a year" or "an year"

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation, articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct- “A Year” or “An Year”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12558/which-is-correct-a-year-or-an-year)
>   [Use of “a” versus “an”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/use-of-a-versus-an)

*A(n) ear* vs. *a(n) year* in speaking is very confusing, please clarify.