# "a" or "an" ubiquitous?

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

I am unsure whether to use "a" or "an" in the following sentence:

`Video games have become a/an ubiquitous part of American culture.`

For me, saying the two sentences out loud makes "an" seem like the right choice but Microsoft Word proofing disagrees.

Comment: Which grammar check version are you using -- UK or US English?

Comment: US English version

Comment: @Jim - I think this is a special case because both are used.

Comment: Depends on whether you say *youbiquitous* like the majority of people nowadays, or *oobiquitous*. Both are equally correct (for now).

Comment: @HansAdler: What dictionaries list "oobiquitous"? This is the first time I've heard of it. It sounds like a mis-pronunciation to me, so I'm curious why you say it is correct - are there certain fields where the term is used where this is a widespread pronunciation?

Comment: Yep, depends on how it's pronounced.  *oobiquitous* is less common, but not exceedingly rare.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK- I believe it's a duplicate because the rule stated in the linked answer still applies. It's the consonant sound or the vowel sound that should determine which you choose.

Comment: @sumelic: None that I am aware of. But if someone pronounces it that way, then this seems totally legitimate to me. And the statistics provided by chasly suggest that the variant pronunciation was actually the standard in the 19th century.

Comment: No-one says 'oobiqitus' and no-one ever has as far as I know. This is a different phenomenon. Some people did and some people still do use 'an' in front of certain words beginning with 'u'. It is pronounced 'an you-biquitous'.  I'll see if I can find examples of other such words. I'm pretty sure that Carl Sagan used to talk like this.

Comment: @Jim - Well there's 'should' and there's what people actually do. There is a long-running debate on when rules win over usage and vice versa.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - I have definitely heard reasonably literate people say "oobiquitous".  However, the pronunciation is often not distinct such that the only "tell" (unless you pay very close attention) is the (optional) indefinite article.

Comment: I just learned that many of the words starting *u-* or *eu-* that are now pronounced with a *yoo-* sound were originally pronounced with an *eeoo-* sound that apparently explains the former use of *an* for them.

Comment: @Hans: which other words like this were formerly used with "an"?

Comment: @sumelic: Basically everything starting with *u* or *eu*. [Examples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+union%2Fa+union%2Can+European%2Fa+European%2Can+eulogy%2Fa+eulogy%2Can+universal%2Fa+universal&year_start=1750&corpus=15)

Comment: @HansAdler: maybe it's related to the phenomenon discussed in these questions: [Why is it “an yearly”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46323/why-is-it-an-yearly), [“a” or “an” for words beginning with “eu”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212544/a-or-an-for-words-beginning-with-eu)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't straightforward. In my version of English, I would say 'a ubiquitous'. It seems that the grammar checkers in MS Word agree -- both in US and UK English.

However, take a look at this ngram of published works.

Google ngram: [a ubiquitous,an ubiquitous](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20ubiquitous%2Can%20ubiquitous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20ubiquitous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20ubiquitous%3B%2Cc0)

You can see that a changeover occurred in the late 1880s but both versions survive up to the present day.

[image]

Comment: That's bizarre. I wonder how all of the people using "an ubiquitous" pronounce it?

Comment: They probably pronounce it "oobiquitous". I have heard several people say it that way.