# Use of 'an' vs 'a'

Tags: grammar, articles, vowels

I am a little confused around the usage of `an` vs `a`

I know the basic vowel rule but the following are the usages that confuse me.Can someone please tell which of the following are correct and the corresponding language rules -

- Success Factors....an SAP company
- it's an year long process
- I only want a yes for an answer

Comment: For first bullet, see [Do you use “a” or “an” before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016) For the second and third bullets bullet:  in modern English, "an year" is wrong and "a yes" is correct. For historical context, see [Why is it “an yearly”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46323)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you use "a" or "an" before acronyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/do-you-use-a-or-an-before-acronyms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the proper rules:

> Success Factors....**an** SAP company
>
> it's **a** year long process
>
> I only want a yes for **an** answer**

But watch out for the vowel rules - they're not always so straightforward:

- **An** 800 number
- **A** unanimous vote
- **An** unanticipated result
- **An** honest decision.
- **An** x-mas tree

http://home.nerbonne.org/A-vs-An/

Comment: I think that, generally, if you were to spell the start of the word **phonetically**, **then** apply the vowel rule, you'll get the right answer. -  "an ess-ay-pee company", "an ayt-hundred", "a you-nan-i-mous", "an onn-est"  etc.  "year" is pretty phonetic already, i don't know why you (questioner) are confused about that one as it seems pretty obvious.  "x-mas" tree is a confusing example because most people would call it "a christmas tree", even if it was *written* "xmas".

Comment: `spell the start of the word phonetically, then apply the vowel rule, you'll get the right answer`. Definitely seems like a viable approach.

Comment: It also gets confusing when there are two ways to pronounce an acronym: [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) may be pronounced either "ess-cue-ell" or "sequel," so depending on the speaker's preference, it could be either "an SQL statement" or "a SQL statement."

Comment: I think the phonetic rule is fundamental, and in my experience extends even to dialetc variants: e.g. "That an 'arf-baked idea" said the Cockney.